# Hide password by ignoring file in .gitignore, but unable to deploy to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I was trying to deploy my Node JS application to Heroku. Heroku was connected to my Github account and deployed through Github. In my Node JS application, I created a SQL pool file `awsPool.js` using the following code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const awsPool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: "myDb.abcdefg.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    user: "myUsername",
    password: "myPassword",
    port: 3306,
    database: 'myDb',
    debug: false
});
module.exports = awsPool;
```

And imported it in my Express application. The pool contains credentials such as my username and password, so I set them as ignored in `.gitignore`. However, when trying to deploy the application to Heroku, Heroku gave me this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './awsPool'
```

I understand this is likely due to `awsPool.js` being not tracked in my Github, but how can I properly hide my credentials and deploy to Heroku?

Comment: Move your credentials to the *environment*, `password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,` for example.

Comment: U need to use `environment variables` in order to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use ponto .env files that will define your credentials. So when you are going to deploy your application on Heroku you will only need to define your environment variables